# Animate the peeling of top sealed packaging

Tags: animation, mesh, modifiers

I'm working on my first blender project for a product concept. It's comprised of a cup and seal (both seperate objects), of which I want to give the top seal an animation of being pealed off.

The best comparison would probably be instant noodles, where you remove this seal by pulling. I tried using the simple deformation and hook modifiers, without the desired effect. 
I've attached pictures of the viewport and mesh.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image: Cup with seal that needs peeling off animation]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, hook is right way. But, you need to add some Cloth Simulation.

[image]

To make cloth appeal like a plastic seal, I reduce mass, add more Viscosity and add more bending stiffness:

[image]

Next, you need to "Pin" vertexes, that are glued to top of a cup. Also, vertexes (that are moving by hook) must be pined. I made it from edit mode, but display in weight paint for appeal:

[image]

Pinned group in "Shape" panel in Cloth settings:

[image]

And here is a tricky part. You should unpin vertexes during animation. I use Vertex Weight Proximity modifier for this.

Add 2 planes: one hover "hooked" vertexes, and one for glued:

[image]

Last one will move and free pinned vertexes:

[image]

Combine two planes into one object using Boolean modifier with Union type. and use result in Vertex Weight Proximity modifier. Setup modifier like this. Note, that the Lowest value more than Highest and distance by geometry.

[image]

Here the modifier stack. Note, that Hook is before Cloth and Vertex Weight Proximity before Hook.

[image]

Also, I added smooth and solidify.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for! 

I do have a few questions on how to do this though. 

Do you have one or two vertex groups?

I've pinned a single group with both the glued and hook part, then I added the two separate planes. I combined the two planes using the boolean modifier, do you have to apply this first? Then, in the vertexWeightProximity, there are no groups listed. Is there any thing I'm doing wrong? I've added the .blend file to the post.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do not apply Boolean modifier - it's need to be animated. One part moves, second - not. Of course, you can move second part in different way, for example via hook, or shape key. Vertex Weight Proximity is on moving part - this modifier edits pinned vertex group

Comment: I noted, that in your file something wrong with lid. To fix it, M (alt+M) -> merge by distance.

Comment: And I noted, Normalize Weights are in 2.90 only =(

Comment: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/NgqWwnWJ/ here the result. Works in 2.90 and 2.83 (maybe Normalize Weights is enabled in 2.83 without setting)

Comment: Thank you so much for all the effort you put in! It's perfect :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't describe the way the lid is supposed to open, let say it rolls around itself, what you can do is create a bezier curve over the lid, put its origin at its beginning, make it whirl at its end, and make sure its direction is correct (from origin to whirl). Now give your lid object a *Curve* modifier with the curve as *Object*, when you move the curve the lid roll around itself. You could also create a flat curve and give it bones to control it but it would be longer.

[image]